# How to order the order of returned API calls with generators?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, generator

I'm practicing some more advanced Javascript techniques, and came across generators and iterators as something I wanted to look into. I know that I'm doing this incorrectly, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

The idea of my little program is this: I want to make API calls to the OpenWeather API for four (or more, but I'm testing with four) cities. The cities are stored in an array and one by one, the city is appended to the URL and a fetch request is sent. Each response is appended to an array and the array is sent to the client. 
This was my original code:

```
// node/express setup here

const cities = ["London%2Cuk", "New York%2Cus", "Johannesburg%2Cza", 'Kingston%2Cjm']

const url = process.env.URL_BASE;

const headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": process.env.HOST,
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.API_KEY
}

const requestInit = { method: 'GET',
           headers: headers
        };

const fetchWeather = (ep) => {
    const appendedURL = url + ep;
    return fetch(appendedURL, requestInit)
        .then(r => r.json());
}

app.get('/', (req, res, err) => {
     const data = []
     Promise.all(
        cities.map( async (city) => {
            await fetchWeather(city)
            .then(returns => {
                data.push(returns)
            })

         })
     )
     .then(() => {
        res.send(data)
        return data;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))   
})
```

Right? Solid, works ok. But now I'm stuck on how to order it. The way I would think to do this is to switch `await fetchWeather(city)` to `yield fetchWeather(city)` and have a generator manager that would continue calling `next(city)` until the array had completed, but I'm having an issue figuring out the pattern. I refactored the api call to a generator and am testing out a generator management function.

The paradigm I have based on my understanding is this:

- First `.next()` starts the iteration
- Second `.next(args)` passes the designated city to the first yield
- Third `.next()` sends the yielded fetch request and should (ideally) return the response object that can be `.then()`'d.

Here is my tester generator code:

```
function *fetchWeather() {
    for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
        const appendedURL = url + (yield);
         yield fetch(appendedURL, requestInit)
        .then(r => {
            return r.json()
        });
    }
}

const generatorManager = (generator) =>{

    if (!generator) {
        generator = fetchWeather();
    }

    generator.next()
    generator.next(cities[i])
    generator.next().value.then( e => 
        console.log(e));
}
```

I'm getting an error:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` And I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here with my logic. How do I refactor this to allow me to wait for specific promises if I can't individually pass known values? I know there has to be a way, but I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what benefit you hope to get from using a generator here, but the reason you're getting that error is you're doing one to many `.next()`'s

The first `generator.next()` runs fetchWeather until the first yield, which is the yield at the end of `const appendedURL = url + (yield);`. The return value from calling `generator.next()` in this case is `{ value: undefined, done: false }`

After that, `generator.next(cities[i])` resumes fetchWeather, with `cities[i]` being the result of the previous yield. The generator continues running, calling `fetch`, then calling `.then` on that promise, and then yielding the resulting promise. So the return value that generatorManager sees from doing  `generator.next(cities[i])` is `{ value: /* a promise object */, done: false }`.

So to fix that error, you need to reduce the number of calls you're making to generator.next

```
generator.next()
generator.next(cities[i]).value.then(e => 
  console.log(e));
```

As mentioned in the comments, the usual way i'd do this is map the cities to promises, and then do promise.all. For example:

```
Promise.all(
  cities.map((city) => fetchWeather(city)) // note, this is the original fetch weather, not the generator
).then((data) => {
  res.send(data);
  return data;
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: In fairness, I don't really have a good use case on hand for a generator in general, so the idea behind this is more to get to know how to best order promises. The idea is that I want to see my responses in the exact order I'm sending them, even if the second or the third comes first.

Comment: For that, i'd just map the cities to an array of promises, and then do promise.all. Would you like an example of what that looks like?

Comment: I'd love to see it, as that's a paradigm I'm wholly unfamiliar with, but I have to ask, what makes mapping the promises to the cities and resolving all of those at once more sequential than sending the calls one by one? Is that just the native behavior of `Promise.all()`

Comment: I've added an example in. It's not doing them sequentially. It kicks off all of the fetches at the same time. Each fetch has its own promise, and promise.all creates a promise that will resolve once all the individual promises resolve. That outer promise resolves with an array containing all the things the inner promises resolved to (in the order they were passed to promise.all, not in the order they resolved)

Comment: But so I'm getting this right btw?
 - First next() starts the generator returning undefined, executing until first yield in the assignment expression
 - Second next() passes the cities value to the assignment, execution resumes and the fetch is sent 
- Second yield sets the return value of the previous next() to that promise, which is thenable
That's the general idea, right? the second next will hit the first yield, the third will hit the second yield, and so on?

Comment: I see the snippet! It didn't even occur to me that you could run a function in a Promise.all() to create the mapping on the fly. Thanks again!

Comment: the first `next()` runs from the top of the generator to the first yield. The second `next()` runs from the first yield to the second yield.